# facebook graph api 601 exception. getting exception in the graph api

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, graph

I'm new to graph API... I'm running the FQL query in the graph API

```
SELECT name, FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

I'm getting this error...

please help me.. thanks in advance

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected 'monthly_active_users' at position 0.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 601
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

remove the coma after name
if you want to add more selection add coma

like this

```
SELECT name,id FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

this video link might help you better understandign in fql

[link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfT4NBcTe_8)